# docker-compose up returns OSError: Can not read file in context: .../data/mmaps/5332641.mmtile

Tags: docker-compose, debian, azerothcore

Followed the instructions from here: http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker

I used the v8 data

When I run docker-compose up I get the following:

```
Building ac-worldserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 97, in create_archive
  File "tarfile.py", line 1972, in addfile
  File "tarfile.py", line 250, in copyfileobj
  File "tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 367, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1106, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 160, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 31, in tar
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 100, in create_archive
OSError: Can not read file in context: /home/azerothcore/wotlk/azerothcore-wotlk/docker/worldserver/data/mmaps/5332641.mmtile
[21981] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to `5332641.mmtile`, can you check the permission of `5332641.mmtile`? try to put it with `$ chmod 775` or 777, just to be sure that is not a permission problem.

Comment: I think it had something to do with running out of disk space on that particular partition. I gave up, and went with the classic installation. 12 short hours later, and I'm having a blast playing with my kids! Cheers.

Comment: My case, i simply switch to WSL to execute the docker-compose up and build. It works.

Answer (score 7):

It is likely disc space related, i had same error and there is an error above it that indicates the build ran out of disc space. Works after clearing space it uses over 10gb in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to mount a large file. The solution for me was to create a .[dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file containing the name of the directory where the large file was saved.